# Changing Z-Index Of Another Element On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in the code below I am trying to figure out how can I change "content"s z-index relatively to clicked "menu-item". I managed how to do this for menu items, but cannot find solution for the rest. In simple words I need to click #m1 and set Z-Index 10  for #c1 and so on.

HTML

```
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div id="c1" class="content">content1</div>
    <div id="c2" class="content">content2</div>
    <div id="c3" class="content">content3</div>
    <div id="c4" class="content">content4</div>
</div>
<div id="menu" class="container">
    <div id="m1" class="menu-item"></div>
    <div id="m2" class="menu-item"></div>
    <div id="m3" class="menu-item"></div>
    <div id="m4" class="menu-item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*global*/
.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
/*content*/
.content{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    right: 0;
    background: #354458;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 95px;
}
/*menu*/
.menu-item{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in-out;

}
.menu-item.closed{
    left: 0 !important;
}
#m1{
    left:0;
    background: #DB3340;

}
#m2{
    left: 25%; 
    background: #E8B71A;
}
#m3{
    left: 50%; 
    background: #1FDA9A;
}
#m4{
    left: 75%; 
    background: #28ABE3;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var menu = $('.menu-item');

    menu.click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(menu).css('z-index', "initial");
        $(this).css('z-index', 11);
    });
    menu.click(function(){
        menu.toggleClass("closed");
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8a3vqy5v/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to register multiple click events for the same element, they serve for your case same as a single binding.

You can hide and show the background content based on the menu index as follows within the click event, you can check the code snippet for full code:

```
var index = $(this).index();
$('.content').hide();
$('.content').eq(index).show();
```

**Snippet :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var menu = $('.menu-item');
 
 menu.click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(menu).css('z-index', "initial");
  $(this).css('z-index', 11);
        menu.toggleClass("closed");

        var index = $(this).index();
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.content').eq(index).show();
 });

});
```

```css
/*global*/
.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
/*content*/
.content{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    right: 0;
    background: #354458;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 95px;
}

/*menu*/
.menu-item{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in-out;
    
}
.menu-item.closed{
    left: 0 !important;
}
#m1{
    left:0;
    background: #DB3340;
    
}
#m2{
    left: 25%; 
    background: #E8B71A;
}
#m3{
    left: 50%; 
    background: #1FDA9A;
}
#m4{
    left: 75%; 
    background: #28ABE3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div id="c1" class="content">content1</div>
    <div id="c2" class="content">content2</div>
    <div id="c3" class="content">content3</div>
    <div id="c4" class="content">content4</div>
</div>
<div id="menu" class="container">
    <div id="m1" class="menu-item"></div>
    <div id="m2" class="menu-item"></div>
    <div id="m3" class="menu-item"></div>
    <div id="m4" class="menu-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the index of the clicked `.menu-item` element and then select the corresponding `.content` element using the index with the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5r3ge13h/)

```
var $menu = $('.menu-item');

$menu.click(function() {
  $(this).css('z-index', 11).siblings($menu).add('.content').css('z-index', '');

  if (!$(this).hasClass('closed')) {
    $('.content').eq($(this).index()).css('z-index', 10);
  }
  $menu.toggleClass("closed");
});
```

But since that creates a weird transition bug, you could use the code from [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/skj19xLL/) instead. It essentially listens to the `transitionend` event.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however even the one in the example crashes some animation. The first blocks is jumping.

Comment: The down side with your code is that when the menu closes content 4 always shows which ruins the effect..

Answer (score 0):

if there is a fixed number of elements (ie: 4) you could simply throw 4 rules, one for each :

```
$('#m1').click(function() {
    $('.content').css('z-index', '');
    $('#c1').css('z-index', '11');
});
$('#m2').click(function() {
    $('.content').css('z-index', '');
    $('#c2').css('z-index', '11');
});
$('#m3').click(function() {
    $('.content').css('z-index', '');
    $('#c3').css('z-index', '11');
});
$('#m4').click(function() {
    $('.content').css('z-index', '');
    $('#c4').css('z-index', '11');
});
```

if you want a single rule that would apply to any `#mx` - `#cx` couple, you could also try to get the id of the element clicked as a string and manipulate the string in order to replace the first letter with a 'c'